# Trying to open modal if adblock is detected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to detect a adblock, i am doing that with jquery, and if user has adblock, it should open a bootstrap modal, if user hasent, i should just leave the modal hidden. here is my code

The var canRunAds is in the ads.js folder, and is not a problem getting loaded, i have testet it with alert(); instad and there it is working fine :)

```js
var canRunAds = true;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Farvel Sælgere!</title>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="../Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../Scripts/ads.js"></script>
        <script>
            if (window.canRunAds === undefined) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            } else {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself, yeay! Had to add the document ready! so i change the script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                if (window.canRunAds === undefined) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the script tags at the bottom of the body tag, like this

```
<body>
  ...
  <script src="..."></script>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
</body>
```

If you write javascript before, the DOM nodes you're looking for (i.e. `#myModal`) won't exist when the javascript runs.

This also has the benefit of not blocking render while the JS files are being downloaded.

`$(document).ready()` works, but you should move all JS files to the bottom of the body as well. (there are also async/defer attributes that make JS in the head OK, but don't worry about these for now).

Read through [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) and the related documents for more info.